# Can a Christian or Jehovah witness change religion?

Tags: marriage, jehovahs-witnesses, religion

I have a boyfriend we are okay and happy to each other until one day he asked my religion. I said I'm a Christian and he said to me that we can't be together because he's a member of JW and I'm not from his church. I said we can find a way and he trust what I said.

My question is can a Christian and unbaptized Jehovah Witness can be marriage? If not can be one of us change religion?

In case someone say that I'm crazy because I'm willing to change a religion just for someone. I just believe that it is not in religion when it comes on God it is about your faith and trust in him.

Comment: The other question gives you the answer about marriage. Obviously either of you can change your religion if you wish and value your significant other above your beliefs, though possibly not without consequences from your families or communities.

Comment: Did you know that Jehovahs witnesses are Christians?  I don’t think your boyfriend takes his affiliation with Jehovah’s Witnesses very seriously.

Comment: [This answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/74718/can-a-non-baptized-jehovahs-witness-publisher-date-a-non-believer) may be helpful as well

Comment: It doesn't appear we have a question about it, but all Protestants and Catholics would strongly caution their adherents not to marry non-Trinitarians (including Jehovah's Witnesses). Both sides think it is extremely unwise, as they do not consider the other side to worship the same God! As you say, it's all about trusting God, which means that truly knowing him, knowing the right identity for God, is essential. If you can come to the same place theologically, then marriage is a wiser option.

Comment: Hmmm this is an interesting dilemma, most unequal yoking is thought of in terms of christianity vs secularism. However, i would argue interdenominational unequal yoking may have equally difficult issues because fundamentally, its about peoples world views. Having said that, Jesus didn't start a denomination as such. Anyway, here is a website I googled that has biblical passages on unequal yoking.  Make of it what you will. My suggestion...both of you change denominations to one where you can find commonality and compromise in your existing world views. https://biblereasons.com/unequally-yoked/

Comment: @Kris Jehovah's Witneses consider themselves Christians but they don't consider other Christians to really be Christians.

Comment: @DJClayworth  that is explained in part [here](https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/wp20120301/Are-All-Christians-Christian/).   For the purpose of this site any group self identifying as Christian are considered to be Christian.

Comment: By far the most important consideration is the community in which you and your husband plan to raise your children. You will find that deciding **what kind of religious upbringing** you give your children will trump everything else, since it will be embodied in the kind of Christians you will associate & spend a lot of time with: their worldview, their ethical values, their doctrines, etc. which their Sunday school teachers will indoctrinate them.  "Indoctrinate" sounds negative, but that's exactly what will happen, until they become adult and can decide for themselves. That's your legacy.

Comment: Be fully aware what you are signing up to.  Research the religious groups you are considering.  Do not just ask them, either the JWs or a Christian group what they believe, find out as much as you can from the internet first, and other sources. A few hours research could save you a lifetime of relationship struggles, inner turmoil, and regret.