# Marriage to a Jehovah’s Witness is it possible?

Tags: bible, marriage, jehovahs-witnesses

My girlfriend is a Jehovah’s Witness and I am a [MFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_of_Fire_and_Miracles_Ministries) member. But I love her so much! Can I marry her?

Comment: This is a question your girlfriend will need to raise with the elders

Comment: There are a few problems with this question. (1) It's asking for pastoral advice - personal advice about what *you* should do in your specific condition. We don't answer those questions here - it's not a good idea to rely on strangers for advice, and on here we answer questions with objective, not personal, answers. (2) You need to explain what "MFM" means. (3) are you asking whether the MFM group would be OK with this? The Jehovah's Witnesses? Someone else?

Comment: For the perspective of Jehovah's Witnesses (of which I am one), I recommend the film: [What Is True Love?](https://www.jw.org/finder?srcid=share&prefer=content&applanguage=E&locale=en&item=pub-ivtru_2_VIDEO&docid=1011214)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  This is how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809

Comment: Does MFM stand for [**Mountain** of **Fire** and **Miracles** Ministries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_of_Fire_and_Miracles_Ministries)?

Comment: Mountain of Fire and Miracle Ministries appears to have Pentecostal roots. Its founder (Daniel Olukoya) has written books such as 'Deliverance from Spirit Husband and Spirit Wife (Incub and Succubi)' and ' Overpowering Witchcraft'. I'm voting to close this question because (a) a full answer can be found in the link provided by Kris and (b) this question is not within the scope of Christianity Stack.

Answer (score 1):

Some sources from the Jehovah's Witnesses org website:

https://www.jw.org/en/publications/jw-meeting-workbook/december-2017-mwb/meeting-schedule-dec25-31/what-is-true-love-questions/#?insight[search_id]=9870c244-2adb-41a0-9d24-b641d8a1d159&insight[search_result_index]=19

https://www.jw.org/en/publications/videos/#en/mediaitems/VODMoviesModernDay/pub-ivtru_2_VIDEO

Also this was an older discussion regarding this, and too can provide some information,

[Are Jehovah's Witnesses allowed to marry outside the faith?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4181/are-jehovahs-witnesses-allowed-to-marry-outside-the-faith)