# Do Jehovah’s Witnesses recognize marriage out of their religion?

Tags: marriage, jehovahs-witnesses, divorce

I am dating a Jehovah Witness male who is a marvelous man.  He is divorced from his wife after 22 years of sub standard wife treatment.  I am born and raised Christian and we have open dialog over our religious beliefs.  Does the Jehovah Witness religion recognize marriage out of their religion?

Comment: never mind this site is too slow

Comment: gotta get this marriage cracking, no time for deliberation! lol!

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6587/23657 the accepted answer to this related question may help you

Comment: Jehovah's Witnesses recognize all marriages as valid, but if he remarries when his previous divorce was for an unscriptural reason, he will be committing adultery, and would be disfellowshipped if not repentant.

Comment: Marry in haste, repent at leisure. Marriage is a life-time commitment and should not be entered into lightly. Be aware that Jesus said the only grounds for divorce is adultery - was this Jehovah's Witness wife unfaithful to him? And is he prepared to forego privileges in the congregation if he marries you? Or is he hoping to persuade you to become a baptized Jehovah's Witness? You need to have a serious discussion with this man to clear up these important issues.

Comment: Fir the record  you asked the question 35 minutes before you abandoned the site for being too slow

Comment: @4castle that looks like an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Jehovah’s Witnesses recognise marriage between Witnesses and non-Witnesses.  However, for a divorced Jehovah’s Witness man to remarry he must have divorced his wife on the grounds of her adultery.  He may have a legal document granting him a divorce, but the Bible says the only basis for divorce is adultery.  Here are a couple of quotes from the official Jehovah’s Witness web site:

> Insight on the Scriptures, Volume 1, pages 639-643 – Divorce: What is the only Scriptural basis for divorce among Christians? Jesus said: “I say to you that whoever divorces his wife, except on the ground of fornication, and marries another commits adultery.” (Mt 19:8, 9) Today, generally, distinction is made between “fornicators” and “adulterers.” According to modern usage, those guilty of fornication are unmarried persons who willingly have sexual relations with someone of the opposite sex. Adulterers are married persons who willingly have sexual relations with a member of the opposite sex who is not their legal marriage mate. As shown in the article FORNICATION, however, the term “fornication” is a rendering of the Greek word por·neiʹa and includes all forms of illicit sexual relations outside of Scriptural marriage. Hence, Jesus’ words at Matthew 5:32 and 19:9 mean that the only divorce ground that actually severs the marriage bond is por·neiʹa on the part of one’s marriage mate. The follower of Christ may avail himself of that divorce provision if that is his desire, and such a divorce would free him to marry an eligible Christian.—1Co 7:39.
>
> Nor does the Bible grant Christians the right to divorce their marriage mates because of difference in religion; it shows instead that by remaining with an unbelieving mate the Christian may win that individual over to the true faith.  https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001202
>
> Honor “What God Has Yoked Together” Watchtower (Study) 2018 - The Only Scriptural Grounds: On two occasions, Jesus indicated that the only grounds for a divorce that would free an innocent mate to remarry is por·neiʹa. What does that Greek term mean? Por·neiʹa applies to illicit sexual relations outside Scriptural marriage. It includes adultery, prostitution, and sex relations between unmarried individuals as well as oral and anal sex and the sexual manipulation of the genitals of an individual to whom one is not married.  https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2018683

I have no idea what you mean by saying this man is “divorced from his wife after 22 years of sub- standard wife treatment” and all I can suggest is that you get him to explain exactly what the grounds for the divorce were.